# how do I increment a second table

Tags: java, tabs

I am a university student and I have an introductory course in Java programming in financial management, and as having no knowledge with Java, I appeal to your expertise in this area to help me solve this little exercise. The statement number 3 see below, I do not know how to create the second table (called Table 2), how do I increment a second table.

We have the following integer array of size 7:

25 10 45 34 3 56 78

1) Create the table in your Java program and display it on the screen; (fine)

2) Sort the table and display the result on screen; (fine)

3) Create another table (Table 2 that the call in the following) that contains
     the same values ​​as the above table but that is of size 10;
     (dont get it)

4) Fill the empty boxes of new avecl has value 1. Table 2

5) Sort Table 2 in ascending order and display the result on screen. (Fine)

Here's what I've done so far.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Nombre Entiers pour Tableau 1");
    int nombreEntiers = 7;
    int [] tableau = {25, 10, 45, 34, 3, 56, 78};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tableau));

    System.out.println("Nombre Entiers pour Tableau 2");
    int[] tableau2 = new int [10];
    tableau2[0] = 1;
    tableau2[1] = 1;
    tableau2[2] = 1;
    tableau2[3] = 3;
    tableau2[4] = 10;
    tableau2[5] = 25;
    tableau2[6] = 34;
    tableau2[7] = 45;
    tableau2[8] = 56;
    tableau2[9] = 78;
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(tableau2));
}
}
```

*Sorry is in french. 
- Nombre entiers = intenger in french 
- Tableau = table in french*

Thank you World!

Comment: Hold that! Use a Bubble Sort. Go research it. You'll fail the assignment if you use what you have there! There's no logic, only assignments.

Comment: I don't understand point 3)

Comment: It's a quick referencing drill. You have to research your answer. You'll run across other functions and ways of doing other stuff

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop to put the values from `tableau` into `tableau2` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< tableau.length; i++) {
    tableau2[i] = tableau[i];
}
```

Then you will have `tableau2` with all the `tableau` values with three 0 values at the end.

You can read on [For loop here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Also, don't sort it manually. Use [Arrays sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[]))

Usage: `Arrays.sort(tableau2)` this will sort you array.

Comment: @Mr.Ocean Consider accepting my answer if that helped you :)